# Mittag-Leffler condition and exact sequence of inverse systems

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

In Lang's algebra book page 164, he provided the following theorem:

**Theorem** Given $(A_n), (B_n), (C_n)$ be inverse systems of abelian groups, assume $(A_n)$ satisfies Mittag-Leffler condition. If the sequence $0 \xrightarrow{} (A_n) \xrightarrow{} (B_n) \xrightarrow{g} (C_n) \xrightarrow{} 0$ is exact, then so is the sequence $0 \xrightarrow{} \varprojlim A_n \xrightarrow{} \varprojlim B_n \xrightarrow{g} \varprojlim C_n \xrightarrow{} 0$

It's obvious that the only point is to prove the surjectivity on the right. Let $(c_n)$ be an element of the inverse limit, Lang states that each inverse image $g^{-1}(c_n)$ is a coset of $A_n$, so in bijection with $A_n$. Also, the Mittag-Leffler condition on $(A_n)$ implies the Mittag-Leffler condition on $(g^{-1}(c_n))$. I actually don't understand what he means by "$g^{-1}(c_n)$ is a coset of $A_n$, so in bijection with $A_n$"? Because there are possibilities that $g^{-1}(c_n)$ would lie outside the image of $A_n$ in $B_n$.

Does anyone know what he really means by **a coset of $(A_n)$**? Any helps would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that there is some $b_n\in B_n$ such that $g^{-1}(c_n)=b_n+A_n$.
This follows from the exactness of the sequence $0\to A_n\to B_n\to C_n\to 0$.